# Does the Administrator have all types of permission in the windows os?

Tags: windows, operating-system

Does the administrator have all types of permission in the Windows OS?
all types means can we do any changes in the Windows OS.

1. Can we modify UI of windows?
2. Can we modify all env veriables?

Answer (score 0):

The Administrator does not give you permisions to do everything for example you can't possibly delete system 32 and to answer your questions:

1. No that's impossible
2. Yes you can actually do that